# GeoServer Date ftl showing time stamp rather than just the date

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, tomcat

I had an issue with Geoserver showing my postgresql data in the US (MDY) format rather than the UK / European format (DMY). I fixed this by removing the comment #, and setting the language, to en_GB. In the tomcat6.conf file.

```
# You can change your tomcat locale here
#LANG="en_US"
```

The data now displays on my geoserver outputs as DMY, however HH:MM is also shown when i do a get feature request.

The postgresql field is Date, and Geoserver lists it as a Date in the layer information panel. However i have 00:00 after the date when i click for a GETfeature information request.

**How would I stop 00:00 after the date?**